# MVC 5: On password change using UserManger, Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my MVC(5.1) application. I wanted to add password change.

This is what I have done,

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILicenserepository _licenserepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public AccountController(ILicenserepository licenserepository, IUserRepository userRepository)   
    {
        _licenserepository = licenserepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        //UserManager = userManager;
    }


    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DatePickerDbContext()));
    ....
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
    {
        bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        if (hasPassword)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                IdentityResult result = UserManager.ChangePassword(userId, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
            ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
            if (state != null)
            {
                state.Errors.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

When I run the application I get this error on browser

```
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
```

at line

```
 IdentityResult result = UserManager.ChangePassword(userId, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

I don't know what's wrong.
Is it because I haven't initialized my `UserManger` in constructor?

when I inspect the values in `userId, model.OldPassword and model.NewPassword`, all the values are as I expect. userId holds userId value, oldpassword holds oldpassowrd value and new password holds newpassword value provided from user.

Answer (score 3):

It was my stupid mistake
I had created User like this before

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.Lastname,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                Email = model.EmailId,
                Company = model.Company,
                PasswordHash = model.ConfirmPassword
                UserName = model.UserName,
                DateTimeRegistered = DateTime.UtcNow,
                License = model.SelectedLicense,
                IsApproved = true,
            };
            var result = UserManager.Create(user);
```

Here, the password would not be hashed and be saved as exact string user provides.

That was creating error.

should have provided password while creating the user like

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.Lastname,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                Email = model.EmailId,
                Company = model.Company,
                UserName = model.UserName,
                DateTimeRegistered = DateTime.UtcNow,
                License = model.SelectedLicense,
                IsApproved = true,
            };
            var result = UserManager.Create(user,model.ConfirmPassword);
```

Comment: This gives me enough clue to solve my problem as well... apparently the password in the db wasn't hashed.